# Using a lemmatizer in ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, lemmatization

I have tried using a stemmer but the words it produces are just not upto the mark. It could be great if you could let me know any lemmatizer script there exists for ruby or a lemmatizer gem or an SQL query that bundles out the lemma of a word in the wordnet database.
Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a Porter Stemmer, should behave as you expect: http://stemmer.rubyforge.org/wiki/wiki.pl?HomePage

Install with `gem install stemmer`.

Alternatively, you can try http://github.com/aurelian/ruby-stemmer - this also has links to additional gems to try.

Comment: Stemming is different from lemmatizing. Stemming will take a word and produce a root word devoid of context, so lazy and lazier will stem to lazi ... but with lemmatization it takes context into consideration and produces an actual word (usually) so in the case above both lazy and lazier would be lemmatized to lazy

You can check out the difference using this tool http://morphadorner.northwestern.edu/morphadorner/lemmatizer/example/

Answer (score 4):

Here is a lemmatizer gem.  Should do what you need:

https://github.com/yohasebe/lemmatizer